# How to use dask to quickly access subsets of the data?

Tags: python, dask

One of the main reasons I love pandas is that it's easy to home in on subsets, e.g. `df[df.sample.isin(['a', 'c', 'p'])]` or `df[df.age < 35]`. Is dask dataframe good at (optimized for) this as well? The tutorials I've seen have focused on whole-column manipulations.

My specific application is (thousands of named GCMS samples) x (~20000 time points per sample) x (500 m/z channels) x (intensity), and I'm looking for the fastest tool to pull arbitrary subsets, e.g.

```
df[df.sample.isin([...]) & df.rt.lt(800) & df.rt.gt(600) & df.mz.isin(...)]
```

If dask is a good choice, then I would appreciate advice on how best to structure it.

### What I've tried

What I've tried so far is to convert each sample to pandas dataframe that looks like

```
                  smp     rt       14       15       16       17       18  
0  160602_JK_OFCmix:1  271.0  64088.0   9976.0  26848.0  23928.0  89600.0   
1  160602_JK_OFCmix:1  271.1  65472.0  10880.0  28328.0  24808.0  91840.0   
2  160602_JK_OFCmix:1  271.2  64528.0  10232.0  27672.0  25464.0  90624.0   
3  160602_JK_OFCmix:1  271.3  63424.0  10272.0  27600.0  25064.0  90176.0   
4  160602_JK_OFCmix:1  271.4  64816.0  10640.0  27592.0  24896.0  90624.0
```

('smp' is sample name, 'rt' is retention time, 14,15,...500 are m/z channels), save to hdf with zlib, level=1, then make the dask dataframe with

```
ddf = dd.read_hdf(*.hdf5, key='/*', chunksize=100000, lock=False)
```

but `df = ddf[ddf.smp.isin([...a couple of samples...]).compute()` is 100x slower than `ddf['57'].mean().compute()`.

(Note: this is with `dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dask.dataframe is backed by an HDF file, so every time you do any operation you're reading in the data from disk.  This is great if your data doesn't fit in memory but wasteful if your data does fit in memory.

#### If your data fits in memory

Instead, if your data fits in memory then try backing your dask.dataframe off of a Pandas dataframe:

```
# ddf = dd.from_hdf(...)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=20)
```

I expect you'll see better performance from the threaded or distributed schedulers: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html

#### If your data doesn't fit in memory

Try to reduce the number of bytes you have to read by specifying a set of columns to read in your `read_hdf` call

```
df = dd.read_hdf(..., columns=['57'])
```

Or, better yet, use a data store that lets you efficiently load individual  columns.  You could try something like Feather or Parquet, though both are in early stages:

- https://github.com/wesm/feather
- http://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I suspect that if you're careful to avoid reading in all of the columns at once you could probably get by with just Pandas instead of using Dask.dataframe.

Comment: Really sorry, I lost a zero when I originally posted - it's 20k points per sample, not 2k. 20k x 2k x 500 x 8B = 160GB, not 16GB, so it doesn't fit in memory. Still your answer will be useful when I can work with a subset of samples.

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: Despite data fits in memory my dask isin is 80 times slower than regular pandas'. Is there any other leaver to speed it up?